# How could I delete products and products displays using mysql?

Tags: commerce, database

I am using kickstart commerce and feeds import to import my products in a csv.

I need to delete some products and product displays using mysql in phpmyadmin because I had a bad import execution with mistakes, now they are in phpmyadmin, but they are not showing up in my backend admin views, I can't reimport again because it says "no new nodes" when I try to reimport althought I have checked replace items.

Please,, what mysql commands can I use to delete any products and products displays, that fits my condition, for example where title='%mypattern%'.

Thank you.

Comment: anytime you do something major like this, before doing that, you should backup your Database.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that. Products are fieldable entities, and if you delete commerce products in database directly, you will have rubbish remaining there. You should use the api call commerce_product_delete(). http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_delete/7

Sample code (please note, that I have not actually tried it, use for reference: Entity queries: https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708):

```
<?php 

$pattern = 'mypattern%';

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_product')
  ->propertyCondition('title', $pattern, 'LIKE')

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['commerce_product'])) {
  $ids = array_keys($result['commerce_product']);
  commerce_product_delete_multiple($ids);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexei Rayu, I am trying to do with mysql because just I am starter in module programming, please what would be the drupal code to delete products and product displays where title like '%sometitle%'?

Comment: Updated my response with the sample code.